# Should I replicate files stored on a windows file share into a data lake?

Tags: file, storage, share

I am working with a team that has a store of unstructured data they maintain on a traditional windows file share (network drive, z:/ drive, etc...). I presume to effectively work with this data in a data lake at the speed at which the team needs, that the data should be copied to a storage location (in my case azure blob storage), then analytics performed on this data.

Regardless of technology, does anyone have experience with a similar challenge? If so, have you just gotten the team to migrate their files, create a replication routine, or just left these "source" files in place?

Note; these mostly happen to be Excel files in my case, but I have to imagine the design pattern would hold regardless of file type.